# Collect resources (ie. properties files) for Install4J from remote machines

Tags: install4j

I need to collect a property file from a remote machine for my software to be installed using Install4J. Does Install4J provide functionality to collect/transfer files from remote locations to the local environment to proceed through installation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a "Download file" action to download a file from a URL to

```
${installer:sys.resourceDir}/my.properties
```

which is the temporary directory of the installer. In further actions you can refer to the downloaded file with the above syntax.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response! This is exactly what I needed it. I must have missed it in the documentation.